# Will my server's hard drive fail/break if it's writing 5 bytes 111,000 times a minute?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a script that's calculating different combinations for my website for a project I'm working on. It's writing 5 bytes to one file and then erasing it and writing to it again over and over. It does this 111,000+ times a minute and will be doing for 7 hours straight. Will this put a strain on my hard drive or is this okay to do?

The CPU is at avg 12%.

Comment: Why not do this in RAM?

Comment: No particular reason I didn't chose RAM I just didn't.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using mmap instead.

Comment: Writing data to a drive is ordinary use.

Comment: What filesystem?  You're probably not actually writing to the disk that often and you may even be writing to a new disk block when it does flush out of cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your drive can take the wear & tear.  I suspect a fair amount of this is cache activity anyway, unless you did something to prevent it from caching.

Comment: I don't think I did, and if I did it was unintentional.